# How to add KRename to context menu

Tags: batch-rename, nautilus-actions

How do I add KRename to the context menu so I can select files and use right click to rename them from the contextual pop up?

I want to do this to make bulk or batch renaming of files faster so I don't need to open up KRename and manually navigate to the folder each time when I already have the folder I want to work with opened.

Comment: suggested tag "krename" I'm unable to add due to low reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution For KRename 4.0.9 - Nautilus-Actions 3.2.3 - Ubuntu 14.04*

### 1. First you will need KRename, of course.

a - Open software center, search for **krename**, install it.

(or **`sudo apt install krename`** in terminal)

### 2. Next you will need the Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool.

This application allows you to customize commands to add to your context menu (the pop up when you right click on a file)

a - Open Ubuntu Software Center

b - Search for and install **Nautilus-Actions Configuration tool**

### 3. Now you want to open Nautilus Actions Configuration Tool.

a - On your sidebar click to open "Dash", the top-most icon (by default) which allows you to search your computer for installed applications.

b - Search for **nautilus actions** and click to open the Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool.

c - Click Define New Action (top left-most icon with the green +)

d - The Action tab should be open. For Context label enter **Bulk Rename With Krename** or anything that best describes this command to you.

e -  Click the command tab. For path enter **/usr/bin/krename**

f - For parameters enter **%B**

g - Check that Working Directory is **%d**

h - *optional* - put this custom command at root of context menu (save yourself extra mousing to open)

h1 - Click the Edit Your Preferences Icon (wrench/screwdriver)

h2 - Uncheck **Create a root Nautilus-Actions menu** and click okay

i - Click File -> Save

j - Exit program

k - You may have to log out of your user account and back in for the setting to take effect. You may even have to reboot, I forget.

### 4. Test it

a - open a folder with files you want to rename

b - select some of them

c - right click on selected files, you should see the option **Bulk Rename With Krename** *(or nautilus actions -> bulk rename with krename)*

If done correctly it will open up KRename and the selected files will be automatically added to work with more fasterer.